# The Java fx Engine fails when loading "PNG" image files to my Java Fx app

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

am a true beginner in `Java Fx` and am having problem loading two png files I found on the web into my app. Can someone advise me what might be wrong please? Below the code I am using:

```
    Button fButton = new Button("Agregar selección");

    Image imageF = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("forwardArrow.png"))
    fButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageF));
```

For some reason the Java Fx graphics engine is failing.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Below the error am getting:

```
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're importing the wrong Image class?
Below is a working example.

```
package com.test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button fButton = new Button();
        Image imageF = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("forwardArrow.png"));
        fButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageF));
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(fButton);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```